Sagnac effect viewed in the rotating frame
Consider the Sagnac effect. It is quite simple viewed from the rest inertial frame what the time difference should be. However, if viewed from the frame fixed to and rotating together with the emitter/detector, since the speed of light should be the same in both directions, the light signals in both directions should return back at the same time. Does this mean two events that happen at the same point in the 4-dimensional space-time in one frame can be at two distinct points in another? I am aware that the reference frame fixed to the emitter/detector is a non-inertial reference and is rotating. I suppose the non-inertiality, specifically the rotation, is the catch. Am I right? In this case the two points coinciding in the space-time of a non-inertial reference frame become two distinct points in the space-time of the inertial reference frame, where the time coordinates are different while the space coordinates are the same. Can it happen where a single point in a non-inertial frame become two distinct points differing in both time and space coordinates in the inertial frame?


from the frame fixed to and rotating together with the emitter/detector, since the speed of light should be the same in both directions

The speed of light is not usually isotropic in a non inertial frame. Einstein’s 2nd postulate only says that the speed of light is $c$ in an inertial frame.
In this case, finding the speed of light in the non-inertial frame can be done as follows. First, we start with the metric in rotating cylindrical coordinates in units where $c=1$: $$ds^2 = -(1-r^2 \omega^2) \ dt^2 + dr^2 + r^2 \ d\phi^2 + dz^2 + 2 \ r^2\  \omega \ d\phi \ dt$$ Then for light we set $ds^2=0$, and for a circular path we set $dr=dz=0$. So the speed of light in this frame is given by solving the above to get $$r\frac{d\phi}{dt}=-r\ \omega \pm 1$$So in the rotating frame the speed of light is not $\pm 1$ (in units where $c=1$), but you have to subtract off the tangential velocity $r\ \omega$

Does this mean two events that happen at the same point in the 4-dimensional space-time in one frame can be at two distinct points in another?

The term for a “point” in 4D spacetime is an “event”. Coordinate systems are a one-to-one mapping between events in spacetime and points in $\mathbb R^4$. So something that is one event in one frame cannot be two events in another frame.

By "two events that happen at the same point", I mean the two events or two points coincide or are identical.

"The speed of light is not usually isotropic in a non inertial frame." It is with respect to the inertial frame instantaneously moving together with the emitter/detecter, right? Should we use this instantaneous inertial frame or the rotating frame fixed to the emitter/detector? If it is the latter, how to compute the light signal speed in the latter frame?

In any inertial frame it is $c$. As you already mentioned, the effect is easy to calculate in an inertial frame.

As I said, I want to view this in the frame fixed to the emitter which is noninertial. How do we compute the time difference and light speed in this noninertial frame?

@Hans you start with the metric in the rotating reference frame. See section 2.1.5 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.4184 Then you solve the geodesic equation. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity and use an initial condition such that $ds^2=0$ to get the path of a pulse of light

Actually, in this case you don’t need to solve the geodesic equation since you want a circular null path. So you just take the metric, set $ds^2=0$ and $dr=dz=0$ and solve for $d\phi/dt$

I think you got the derivation of the rotating frame metric backwards. The metric you presented is simply the Minkowski metric under the transformation $d\phi\to d\phi+\omega dt$. You seem to have just derived the Galilean transformation with simple arithmetic addition for velocities on the perimeter of the circle. I seriously suspect this is wrong.

@Hans that is the standard metric for a rotating frame. See section 2.1.5 here https://arxiv.org/abs/0904.4184

Then how do you reconcile it with the Lorentz transformation and the associated velocity addition?

@Hans the Lorentz transformation is a transformation between inertial frames, it doesn't apply since the rotating frame is non-inertial. And the velocity addition is the composition of two Lorentz transforms, again between inertial frames.

Rotation is defined within a Euclidean space. The space and the associated metric selected makes it not a rotation but translation since there is only one spatial dimension. $d\phi\to d\phi+\omega dt$ is a translation with uniform speed $\omega$. As an example, your same rationale applied to the metric in the cartesian coordinates $ds^2= -dt^2+dx^2$ with $ds=0,, dx\to dx+\beta dt$ would have arrived at the same conclusion $\frac{dx}{dt}=\pm 1-\beta$. Is that the speed of light with respect to the moving frame?

@Hans it is still a rotation. The Killing vector field associated with $\phi$ is a rotation field, not a translation field. The transformation $x \rightarrow x + \beta t$ is a perfectly legitimate coordinate transformation. Indeed, you do get the same conclusion $dx/dt=\pm 1-\beta$ for the speed of light in that frame. This indicates that this frame is not an inertial frame and the transform is not a transformation between inertial frames. If you have additional followup questions please ask them as full questions so that I can give a good full response. Comments are too limited

I put up a full question, as you requested, here physics.stackexchange.com/q/815503/17354. I would appreciate your contribution.

@Hans thanks for the reminder. I saw it the day you put it up but was busy that day and forgot to return to it later. I will respond shortly


However, if viewed from the frame fixed to and rotating together with
the emitter/detector, since the speed of light should be the same in
both directions, the light signals in both directions should return
back at the same time.

In the accelerated rotating reference frame, the speed of light is not the same in both directions globally. If this observer sends light signals simultaneously in opposite directions around the perimeter, they will return to her at different times. The speed of light going clockwise is measured to be different to the speed of light going anti-clockwise in a rotating reference frame. Locally, the speed of light is constant and isotropic in the accelerating reference frame. For example is our observer places two mirrors a short distance apart on the perimeter and sends a signal from the centre, they will return at the same time, so locally the speed of light appears constant and isotropic. There is a similar situation in the gravitational field. the speed of light is constant locally, but over greater distances it is not. In both cases this is due to the fact that the spacetime geometry is not Euclidean in an accelerating reference frame.

In this case the two points coinciding in the space-time of a
non-inertial reference frame become two distinct points in the
space-time of the inertial reference frame

This never happens in Special or General relativity. One event is always one event, in any reference frame or under any transformation.

You are saying even though locally the speed of light is isotropic and
constant, it is not in the "integration" in some yet to be defined
sense, right? – Hans

It is not about integration. When I said the light is locally isotropic, I should have been more clear. Locally the light is anisotropic but appears to be isotropic, because when bounced off the mirrors you are measuring the average speed of light rather than the one way speed of light. This is similar to the impossibility of measuring the one way speed of light in a straight line in flat space. In the Sagnac device, this difference in the one way speed of light is exposed when the light completes a complete circle.

I was finding it difficult to explain this concept in words, so I decided to make an animation.
(A) is the point of view of a corotating observer. The two signals go part way round the perimeter to mirrors and return at the same time, so the light appears to be isotropic locally, despite the one way speed being different. The red signal is fast out, but slow back, while the blue signal is fast out and slow back, but the average speed is the same giving the appearance of isotropy.
(B) is also in the rotating reference frame, but the signals are allowed to go all the way around and return to the start at different times, making it clear the one way speed of light is anisotropic in a rotating reference frame.
(C) is the point of view of a non rotating observer. Light speed is isotropic from their point of view and the difference in return times is due to the source and receiver rotating.
Note. Due to time dilation, the event of the red photon returning to the emitter is later in C than in B, but I sped up C so that animations are synchronised.

Thank you for your excellent animation. (A) and (C) are clear.
However, (B) is simply (C) viewed from the coronating observer under
Galilean relativity which contradicts Einsteinium relativity. The
former is wrong. - Hans

(B) is not wrong, but perhaps what is confusing is that it is the point of view of a co-rotating observer at the centre rather than on the perimeter. This central rotating observer does not have linear velocity relative to the perimeter, so it is a bit like panning a camera and the transformation is indeed Galilean in this case. You can also note that you agreed (A) is correct and up until the point the signals reflect off the mirrors, (A) and (B) are identical and after that, the signals in B just maintain their velocity. Why shouldn't they? Therefore if A is correct, so is B.
For completeness, what a co-rotating observer, riding on the perimeter measures, is illustrated in the animation below:

The clocks are synchronised in both reference frames using the Einstein synchronisation convention (co-rotating POV on the left).
Using this convention locally, everything is pretty much the same as in the linear SR case. The arc length are length contracted and the clocks time dilated as per the Lorentz transformations. The differences in simultaneity in the different reference frames is also exactly as you would expect from linear SR.
In Relativity, there are two well known postulates, but there is a third unspoken postulate. That is that if an event occurs in one reference frame or set of coordinates, then the same event occurs in any other reference frame or set of coordinates (in SR and GR). In other words, there is only one reality. Einstein presumably felt this went without saying.
For example, both signals returning at the same time to the location of clock B, coincides with clocks B and F being alongside each other in both reference frames and in both reference frames clock B indicates 2 seconds and clock F indicates 3.33 seconds at that event. In both reference frames, clock A passes clock F when A = 0.75 seconds and F = 2.58 seconds. This is difficult to see in the animation without freezing it and is better seen in the original GeoGebra construction here.
It is important to note that when using the Einstein synchronisation method, clocks ahead of the master clock are advanced and clocks behind are retarded. In a rotating reference frame, a problem arises with this method of synchronisation, when you get to a common clock half way around the perimeter, because it is impossible to advance and retard this shared clock at the same time. This is where the difference between local measurements and global measurements is demarcated. When using local measurements, light speed appears isotropic along the perimeter and all measurements are consistent with SR, Lorentz transformations, velocity addition etc. When making global measurements in a rotating reference frame, the difference between the clockwise and anti-clockwise speed of light around the perimeter becomes unavoidable.
Note that the outer ring representing the clocks of the non rotating observer has been drawn larger to try and declutter the animation, but should be treated as having the same radius as the disk of the rotating observer.

My question is exactly what happens to the Lorentzian transformation
particularly the velocity addition/composition. – Hans

By now you can probably guess that relativistic velocity addition in the rotation case, is no different to the linear case and the same equation can be used. In the animation below, two counter-rotating (turquoise blue) objects are measured to have a tangential speed of 0.5c, in the reference frame of the co-rotating observer riding on the perimeter:

In the inertial reference frame, the velocities of the counter rotating objects are exactly as would be calculated using the relativistic velocity addition formula (with relative perimeter velocity of 0.8c). Note that in both reference frames, the light signals arrive at their targets when A and C indicate one second and the turquois objects arrive at their respective clocks when they indicate two seconds as you would expect. However, while they arrive simultaneously in the rotating reference frame, they do not in the inertial reference frame, consistent with SR. The GeoGebra construction for the above animation is here.

You are saying even though locally the speed of light is isotropic and constant, it is not in the "integration" in some yet to be defined sense, right? Can you present and derive this "integration" rigorously?

@Hans See my extended answer in response to your comment.

Thank you for your excellent animation. (A) and (C) are clear. However, (B) is simply (C) viewed from the coronating observer under Galilean relativity which contradicts Einsteinium relativity. The former is wrong. My question is exactly what happens to the Lorentzian transformation particularly the velocity addition/composition.

@Hans I have added to my answer in response to you comment and added a couple more animations. Hope it all make sense now :-)

Thank you for your detailed addition, KDP. Sorry about the delayed response. Let me read your edit carefully and respond afterwards.

The animated GIF below illustrates a fundamental property of the Sagnac effect.

The grey dots represent circumnavigating clocks. It can be clocks that are on Earth, co-rotating with the Earth, or it can be a constellation of orbiting satellites, or any fleet of spacecrafts.
The essential feature is that information is relayed from clock to clock, with the information going around in a loop.
The colored dots represent circumnavigating electromagnetic waves, relayed from clock to clock.
In the animation the red dots and the blue dots propagate at the same velocity. The colored dots move quite fast, so it's hard to see (sorry about that), but you can still see that the cross-over points are consistently at the same locations.

A procedure is necessary to establish self-consistent time-keeping.
With the information travelling around in a loop the only self-consistent procedure is as follows:
Timing pulses are relayed in both directions. The clockwise traveling pulses are are timed such that they are an equal time interval apart. Likewise the counterclockwise traveling pulses are time such that they are an equal time interval apart.
As observed at each of the time-keeping stations: the measured time interval between the red dots is larger than the measured time interval between the blue dots. The angular velocity of the time keeping stations is proportional to the difference in measured transit time. Combined with measurement of the length of the circumference the exact value of the angular velocity follows.
I will refer to this loop-closing synchronization procedure as 'Sagnac synchronization'.

Contrast with Einstein synchronization procedure
Crucially: the loop-closing synchronization procedure is fundamentally distinct from Einstein sychronization procedure.
It is the fact that information is going around in a loop that sets a Sagnac setup apart.
Einstein synchronization procedure is applicable when the information does not go around in a loop.
A typical case is a fleet of spacecrafts arranged along a line. So there are two outer spacecrafts. The outer spacecrafts have no next spacecraft to relay to, so they bounce the information back along the line.

Let's take the specific case of a constellation of satellites, orbiting the Earth. Let the satellites relay timing pulses, but don't close a loop. Instead designate two satellites to bounce the information back. Let that constellation of satellites use Einstein synchronization.
Obviously the synchronization that will result from Einstein synchronization procedure will not coincide with the result of the loop-closing procedure.
Comparison:
When you cross the pacific ocean you cross the international date line; there is a discontinuity. Likewise, if the synchronization procedure does not close the loop (even though the clocks are circumnavigating a center) then there will be a discontinuity.

In many SR textbooks it is suggested that Einstein synchronization procedure is the only candidate for synchronization. However, that suggestion is overreach.
In Minkowski spacetime simultaneity is under-determined; there is leeway. The constraint: a choice of plane of simultaneity must not violate causality; not violating causality is sufficient. Within that constraint there is leeway.
Einsteins synchronization is the symmetrical choice. Within the leeway the choice is arbitrary. But you do need to set up a synchronization, otherwise you can't do any calculation. Since you must choose anyway it makes sense to default to the symmetrical option.
Closing a loop
Closing a loop removes the leeway; once a loop is closed there is only one option for synchronization: Sagnac synchronization.


Discussion
Sagnac synchronization relies on a universally available reference: in all directions the speed of light is the same.
When light/information is propagating along a loop: in clockwise and counterclockwise direction the speed of the propagations is the same. That is the reference.

As depicted in the animation: the grey dots have an angular velocity with respect to the reference.
Conversely:
If you limit the observation to a subsection of the total length then on that subsection you don't have access to Sagnac synchronization. You then fall back on Einstein synchronization. According to that synchronization the speed of light (relative to the time-keeping station) comes out the same in both directions.
Further reading:
2004 article by Olaf Wucknitz:
'Sagnac effect, twin paradox and space-time topology — Time and length in rotating systems and closed Minkowski space-times'

The Sagnac synchronization in your answer is viewed in the inertial reference frame. In that frame the counterclockwise signal takes longer time than the clockwise signal does. But what happens when it is view from the frame fixed on a gray dot?

@Hans To visualize a co-rotating point of view: start with the animation, and add to every element in the animation the same angular velocity. Non-rotating or co-rotating: all the measurement values will be the same. The Sagnac effect presents us with a counter-intuitive property of Minkowski spacetime: application of timed signals going around in a loop gives access to information that without the loop setup you don't have access to. I cannot emphasize this enough: closing a loop matters. We have the following: with a Sagnac setup measurement of angular velocity is not relative.

I understand your conclusion that Sagnac synchronization is different from Einstein one. I am not rejecting this. However, I need the mathematical proof of this conclusion. Particularly, I would very much like you to dispel rigorously my misconception that in the corotating frame that the light signals in the opposite directions propagate with the same speed and traverse the same length and thus return to the emitter at the same time. Please tell me why this is false.

@Hans Please look at the animations in my answer. In the point of view of the non rotating inertial observer (C) the light propagates with equal speed in opposite directions as you would expect. They do not return at the same time because the finish line (the emitter) is moving. Now B is the point of view of a co-rotating observer. This can be simulated by a video camera mounted on the turntable. The outcome must be same in both (B) and (C) as there is only one reality.  B demonstrates that the light must be isotropic in the rotating reference frame. C is speeded up to allow for time dilation.

@Hans If you were to play the animation on a smart phone or tablet and turn the screen clockwise as the animation plays in such a way the the green point in C remains at the top, then animation C would look no different to animation B when the screen is not rotated. P.S. Do you find my answer flawed or unclear?

@Cleonis There is another self-consistent way to synchronise clocks in a rotating reference frame that I will call "central lighthouse synchronisation".  You place a lighthouse at the centre of rotation that sends out an omnidirectional pulse of light, say once per second. The clocks on the rotating perimeter synchronise to the central lighthouse signal. e.g. all the perimeter clocks can be set to zero on receipt of the first signal from the central lighthouse. This way there is no "dateline" as you go around the perimeter.

@KDP What you describe isn't general. There is a type of measuring device called ring laser gyroscope. A ring laser gyroscope measures angular velocity without needing distant reference. The operating principle is the Sagnac effect. That is why in my discussion I use the generic expression 'flow of information'. Your synchronization proposal fails to meet the criterion of being suffiently general: it does not account for the physics that underlies ring interferometry. The ring interferometry case is where the rubber meets the road.

@Cleonis "Without needing distant reference" has never been a constraint of synchronisation conventions. I suspect, our two proposals are mathematically the same and different to the Einstein convention. Both our proposals overcome the dateline issue and the often heard whine that that it is impossible to synchronise clocks globally, because we have both shown it is possible. My proposal has the benefit of conceptual simplicity.

@KDP This is a case of babylonian confusion. My aim is provide understanding of the operating principle of a ring laser gyroscope. How does it measure rotation? I work on the assumption that the reader has absorbed the content of the wikipedia (or equally informative resource) article about the Sagnac effect. I surmise you have no intention to consider how a ring laser gyroscope works. The subject that you are discussing is distinct from the subject that I am discussing. In stackexchange comment space protracted discussion should be avoided.

The OP did not ask about the operating principle of the ring laser. They asked about the "Sagnac effect viewed in the rotating frame" which is exactly what I showed in my animation and what you failed to show in yours, because yours is the point of view of the non rotating frame. The OP also has the misconception that "the speed of light should be the same in both directions" in the rotating frame and you appear to be be suffering from the same misconception when you ....

... say "When light/information is propagating along a loop: in clockwise and counterclockwise direction the speed of the propagations is the same.", because that is simply not true in a rotating reference frame as I have demonstrated in my answer.

The operating principle of a ring laser device does not require the synchronisation of clocks or any clocks at all. A single source can can send signals in both directions and then the interference pattern is analysed on the return of the signals. Similarly a Michaelson-Morley device does not need clock synchronisation, just a common source and an interference pattern. To avoid protracted discussion in stackexchange comment space, do not respond to my comments. BTW, I know exactly how a ring laser works.

@KDP Maybe I should have mentioned this earlier: I started the wikipedia article about the Sagnac effect. While much has changed since my last involvement (2013); the section about Ring lasers is still how I originally wrote it.
The basis: the review of ring lasers by professor G. E. Stedman. Available on archive.org Ring-laser tests of fundamental physics and geophysics

@KDP The wikipedia image ring laser interferometry shift, used in the section 'ring lasers' is a re-creation of a key illustration in professor Stedman's review. The frequencies of the propagating and counterpropagating light tend to remain locked to each other, but with a sufficiently large rotation rate the frequencies unlock, resulting in two frequencies of laser light - thus allowing a beat frequency to be obtained. This frequency shift is unrelated to doppler shift; it is unique to the ring configuration.

Olaf Wucknitz's paper is very informative, wide-ranging and thorough.
